# c - insertBefore linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Ok so I have been working on my first singly linked list project and I have hit a wall. One of the algorithms I am trying to implement is to insert a node before a node specified by the user. The problem I am having is that when the node is inserted it is placed at the correct location but then it also deletes all nodes before it.
If my list originally contained: 1 2 3 4 5
And I wanted to insert 0 before 4
the result is: 0 4 5

```
struct node *insertBefore(struct node *start, int data, int x)
{
    struct node *marker = NULL;
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    struct node *temp = NULL;

    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    marker = start;

    while(marker != NULL && marker->info != x)
    {
        prev = marker;
        marker = marker->link;
    }
    if(!marker)
    {
        printf("*Element containing %d not found*\n", x);
        return;
    }
    if(marker == start)
    {
        temp->info = data;
        temp->link = marker;
        return;
    }
    temp->info = data;
    temp->link = prev->link;
    prev->link = temp;
    temp->link = marker;

    return; 
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, you will find people don't like to answer those kinds of questions here.

Comment: Implementing linked lists is the stereotypical introductory data structures assignment. If you google around, you'll find tons of examples.

Comment: It started out as homework. The requirements were to build a singly linked list with the ability to add and delete nodes. I decided to try and do the other algorithms in my text...insertEnd, insertSelection, insertBefore, and reverseList. I have them all down but this one.

Comment: I understand how its working, I think I do at least. I am just unsure as to why my nodes before my new insertion are getting deleted.

Comment: What is code returning with `struct node *insertBefore(struct node *start, int data, int x)
{ .... 
    return; 
}`?  I'd expect `return some_value;`  Save time - enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Think carefully about what you're doing.

If you are inserting **one** node, you should not create three!

```
temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
marker = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
prev = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The way you should approach this is:

```
// Search for relevant node
while(marker != NULL && marker->info != x) {
    prev = marker;
    marker = marker->link;
}

// Verify you found somewhere to insert
if(marker == NULL) {
    // No x found
    return start;
}

// Allocate and initialize node
struct node* insert_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
insert_node->info = data;
insert_node->link = marker;

if(prev == NULL) {
    // Inserted node is the new start node
    start = insert_node;
}
else {
    // Relink chain
    prev->link = insert_node;
}

// Return the NEW start node.
// This is needed in case the new node is inserted before the original start node!
return start;
```

If you code cleverly (this means thinking!), you can write it very simply and avoid corner cases. Corner cases include:

- Empty input list
- First element is `x`
- No `x` within list

---

Looking at your code again, you're doing a few unusual things. One is that you allocate memory before you're sure that you want to insert an element:

```
temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Also, you change `temp->link` twice, consecutively.

```
temp->link = prev->link;
prev->link = temp;
temp->link = marker;
```

You don't have any mechanism to update the `start` node in case the first element in the list changes.

Comment: Thank you! And yes that was a silly mistake on my part. I need to rename my variables as well. The temp node is what I am using to place into the list. I have it now as  temp->info = data;
 temp->link = prev->link;
 prev->link = temp;

Comment: I am still unsure as to why when I insert the new node it is pushing the nodes behind it (towards the head) out.

Comment: @Austin I've updated the example a bit and added a few notes for you to consider.